# Private Pusher Channels with Laravel, Passport and Client Credentials Grant clients

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-6

I have a Laravel api that uses Laravel Passport for Authentication. I added a client for Client Credentials Grant. Now I want to be able to subscribe a private pusher channel with this client. But I always get 403 Forbidden as http status code.
To the `BroadcastServiceProvider` I added:

```php
Broadcast::routes([
    'middleware' => 'auth.client',
]);
```

In my `routes/channels.php` I added:

```php
Broadcast::channel('user-scanned', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

And I added a new Event:

```php
class UserScanned implements ShouldBroadcast {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = new TimeTrackingUserResource($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn() {
        return new PrivateChannel('user-scanned');
    }
}
```

When I use `auth:api` as Middleware and an access token from a password client, it's working.
The total response from my pusher auth endpoint is:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster.php",
    "line": 44,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager.php",
            "line": 319,
            "function": "auth",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php",
            "line": 261,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastController.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "function": "authenticate",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 219,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 681,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCredentials.php",
            "line": 72,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCredentials",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 683,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 658,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 613,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 170,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 145,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\ovorg-backend\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In `\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster.php` line 43 there is a call to `$this->retrieveUser($request, $channelName)`. It checks, wheather there is a user logged in or not. In my case there is no user logged in, because I use a Client for authentication, but because there is no user, the `AccessDeniedHttpException` is thrown. Does it mean it's not possible to use Pushers private channels with a client and I have to use an user?

Comment: I created an Issue for this. It's not supported by Passport.
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1166